# MySQL Count and Convert Row to Colum Involve One Table Only

Tags: mysql

I have a table name histories that record user activities which consists of user_id, branch_id and duration.

The table look like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id | user_id | branch_id | totHours
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|1 |   100   |     1     |    1   |
|2 |   199   |     1     |    1   |
|3 |   121   |     1     |    1   |
|4 |   140   |     1     |    1   |
|5 |   103   |     2     |    3   |
|6 |   107   |     2     |    1   |
|7 |   299   |     1     |    2   |
|8 |   209   |     2     |    2   |
|9 |   119   |     1     |    5   |
```

I would like to produce an output like this:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Hours | Branch A | Branch B
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|1    |    4    |     1   |
|2    |    1    |     1   |
|3    |    0    |     1   |
|4    |    0    |     0   |
|5    |    1    |     0   |
```

I try make it using this query, but when i use group by on totHours column only, it return error because i need to include the branch_id in the group by.

Here is my query:

```
select totHours as Hours,
   coalesce(case when branch_id = 1 then count(totHours) else 0 end) as 'Branch A',
   coalesce(case when branch_id = 2 then count(totHours) else 0 end) as 'Branch B'
from histories
group by totHours, branch_id;
```

And if the totHours is not in the table (for example in this table 4), it will display 0 for both branch column.

Here is my db [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d5gzRNDf41wFY487QAzeid/0)

Update: MySQL version 5.7.22

Comment: Run `SELECT version();` to check your MySQL version and update to us here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MySQL version 8+ (or any version support windows function), you can make use of the [recursive common table expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive) to generate the hour values for you then `LEFT JOIN` table `histories` with it. After that you can do `SUM()` with `CASE` expression in `SELECT` to generate your expected output:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hours AS (
    SELECT 1 AS hr, MAX(totHours) AS maxth FROM histories UNION ALL
    SELECT hr+1, maxth FROM hours WHERE hr+1 <= maxth)
SELECT hours.hr, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN histories.branch_id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Branch_A,
       SUM(CASE WHEN histories.branch_id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Branch_B
FROM hours
 LEFT JOIN histories 
 ON hours.hr=histories.totHours
GROUP BY hours.hr;
```

If you're using version that doesn't support window function, you can create a subquery to represent the hours (including missing hour). This is a hard-coding approach where you may have to always update the subquery to include new hour value (if any):

```
SELECT hours.hr, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN histories.branch_id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Branch_A,
       SUM(CASE WHEN histories.branch_id=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Branch_B
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 hr UNION 
      SELECT 2 UNION 
      SELECT 3 UNION 
      SELECT 4 UNION 
      SELECT 5) AS hours
 LEFT JOIN histories 
 ON hours.hr=histories.totHours
GROUP BY hours.hr;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2cd3cc31e498841af5b0792c72a68595)

Edit the `hours` subquery to add more, for example if you want until 7, you just add:

```
(SELECT 1 hr UNION 
      SELECT 2 UNION 
      SELECT 3 UNION 
      SELECT 4 UNION 
      SELECT 5 UNION 
      SELECT 6 UNION 
SELECT 7) AS hours
```

to the subquery. Another way is to define the hours beforehand and create a reference table. Let's say you estimate the hour to be until 100, then it's better if you create a table that stores 1-100 as reference for the `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: It works! Btw, how to i count if the value of hours is more than 5?

Comment: I'll add the instruction in my answer.

Comment: i mean if it more than 5, it will count all as 1..for example if there are 8 and 9 hours at branch A, it make last row with value of 2 on column branch A

Comment: You mean something like this? > https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33cd8d70a0f6a30fe20df2e7e7c19490